# For every $n \in \Bbb Z$, prove there exists $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ such that $n = 5a + 2b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was thinking of breaking the $n$ into two cases: one where $n$ is even and one where $n$ is odd. Can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed from here?

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you know Bézout's identity?

Comment: No, we haven't learned this identity in class.

Comment: This is a standard exercise using the extended Euclidean algorithm. In this particular instance $a=1$ and $b=-2$ tells you one way to represent $1$. Then just multiply through by $n$ to represent $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard:

We don't need to look at the cases of even and odd $n$ separately; we have

$\gcd(2, 5) = 1 \Longrightarrow \exists x, y \in \Bbb Z, \; 5x + 2y = 1, \tag 1$

which is known to some as [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), though it is not always referred to as such; then

$n = n(1) = n(5x + 2y) = 5(nx) + 2(ny); \tag 2$

now take

$a = nx, \; b = ny, \tag 3$

and write

$n = 5a + 2b. \tag 4$

As pointed out by Ethan Bolker in his comment, a solution to

$5x + 2y = 1 \tag 5$

is

$x = 1, \; y = -2, \tag 6$

which is easy enough to *guess*; knowing that $x$, $y$ *exist* motivates us to do so.